# Removing a sheet from a LibreOfficeCalc document

Tags: lua, com, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I need to work with a LibreOffice COM object. I was able to get a workbook (not sure if this is the correct name), but I don't understand how to properly delete or create a new sheet. Please show me a simple example. Here's what I did:

```
local _LibreOfffice = luacom.CreateObject("com.sun.star.ServiceManager")
local desktop = _LibreOfffice:createInstance("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop")
self._workbook = desktop:loadComponentFromURL("private:factory/scalc", "_blank", 0, {})


local sheet_count = self._workbook:getSheets():getCount()
for i = sheet_count - 1, 0, -1 do
    local sheet = self._workbook:getSheets():getByIndex(i)
    --remove, but how?
end
```

Comment: Have you searched this site? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71447528/what-is-the-code-to-create-a-new-sheet-in-libreoffice-additionally-how-do-i-re, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70426708/using-ole-remove-all-sheets-except-first-one-from-a-openoffice-libreoffice-calc

Comment: Please, when you study the links kindly provided by @JimK and learn how to use the `.removeByName(Sheet.getName())` methods, be sure to note that your loop `i = sheet_count - 1, 0, -1` will never execute completely, you will always get an error on the last iteration. This is due to the fact that the spreadsheet cannot be completely empty; at least one sheet must remain in it (an attempt to delete the only existing sheet will cause an error)